# How to I maintain parent class property which has the same name as the child class property?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

For example I have code below like so

```
class Foo
  points = 50

class Bar(Foo)
  points = 100
  def alter(self):
     print(self.points) # 100
     print(super().points) # 50
```

How can I effectively change the class variable points in the Foo class from the Bar class? I tried super().points = 300 but it throws an error, the only way I've found is to do Foo.points which seems very inefficient.

Comment: Why do you want this? Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: I have no particular reason, just trying to learn what is the best practice to doing this from the child class. Also curious as to why super().points = 300 wouldn't work.

Comment: one way if you don't want to use `Foo.points` to change `points`, you can also use `self.__class__.__base__.points` (bit different if you have multiple inheritance tho), you can't use `super` because it doesn't return the class itself or sth like that, also again in a case of multiple inheritance what should it do then?

Comment: @Matiiss thank you this seems to work, is this actually preferred over Foo.points, any downsides to using this or not using Foo,points?

Comment: is it preferred? I think not, in most cases really dunder methods are not preferred over alternatives, I personally wouldn't use it but it has the small advantage of always referencing the base class, so in case you change the class name `Foo` to something else, it will still work while `Foo.points` may not. I don't think that internally there is a difference but I would use `Foo.points` over that method because it is easier to read and shorter and doesn't use dunder attributes, but really it is a question of whether it is necessary at all, as stated previously there may be a better solution

Comment: Best practice would be to not do this IMO.  If you need to access these two values independently, the child shouldn't be overriding the parent in the first place.

Comment: @Matiiss if you post an answer, I'll upvote.  This is useful to understand python's internals, but also to work with reflexion and structure-dependent dynamics.

Comment: @Christophe but it's bad practice as mentioned by Samwise, this could in fact lead to confusion about the code, it doesn't help readability so not sure what I even would answer there, it would be simply a possible solution (btw a bit nicer way IMO would be to do `type(self).__base__.points = 300`) which really should never be actually applied. Also not sure what you mean by understanding Python's internals there, maybe I just don't see that, surely this is a dynamic way, however, it shouldn't even come to this, as mentioned